# Managing User Profiles in asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-profiles

I'm trying to add user management to a web app using .net MVC2, similarly to [ProfileProvider: retrieve list of all profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1404381/514087).

I'd like to display profile information (first name, last name) on the "list all users" page, but I can't figure out how to get all profiles.  ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles() returns a collection of *ProfileInfo* objects rather than actual Profile objects.

While the ProfileInfo class does give me access to some useful info, I can't actually get any properties of that particular profile.

Is there a way to get all Profiles in the system so that I can list them on an admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the [MembershipProvider.GetAllUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getallusers.aspx) to get more extensive information about each user. This will give you a collection of [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Darin.  I'm using Membership.GetAllUsers() as a starting point, and that lets me list the users in the system (and set up edit/delete forms).  Unfortunately, it doesn't let me add things like first name, last name, address, etc. to the MembershipUser object.  All I get is username and email.